# Are all intransitive verbs becoming stative with ている?

Tags: grammar

I have been wondering about it for a while, Are all intransitive verbs becoming stative with ている?

Comment: It may interest you: http://web.archive.org/web/20161103070805/http://homepage3.nifty.com/park/aspect.htm

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It seems obvious that there are counterexamples such as 彼が走っている, which refers to a progressive rather than resultative action.

Comment: Ah, and if I'd bothered to read the link first: skip to the part about subject-change vs. non-subject-change verbs.

Comment: The answer is no. Textbooks don't teach this, but there's a room to interpret verbs like 落ちてる as "falling" rather than "fallen", which is of course usually dominant, though.

Comment: Provide an example, since there are exceptions when stating all verbs.